# Function loadModel() returns a "new record"

Tags: php, primary-key, yii

I have the following code for actionUpdate:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    //$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    echo $model->isNewRecord;

    if(isset($_POST['Program']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Program'];

        if($model->save()){

            $this->redirect(array('admin'));
        }
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

The `echo $model->isNewRecord` returns TRUE but the model is not empty. I have an existing model with the given id and the attributes matched the model, so when I call `$model->save()` it gives me

`CDbException CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'.`

I can't find the reason why it is considered as a new record.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's the code for my `loadModel()` function:

```
public function loadModel($id)
{

    $model=Program::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: may be this error basically showing you have not added autoincrement your primary key (database), and when inserting record it is using already inserted record id.

Comment: Thanks but I already have autoincrement in my primary key and I don't think the problem is with the id. I am trying to update an existing record within the database. The problem is that the controller recognises the instance as 'new' which is confusing since I used loadModel() and the function is for update.

Comment: It does not help that you failed to show the loadModel() function.

Comment: I edited and added the loadModel function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CActiveRecord performs the isNewRecord test only after performing afterSave().

So at that point in your code $model->isNewRecord was not tested yet.

Maybe in your situation, it is better to set your own flag (or model attribute), since you anyway know that it is not a new record at that point in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried setting the attribute $model->isNewRecord to false every update action and it worked, but it's just a temporary fix. I'm still hoping to find the correct solution to this.

Comment: Sometimes I just test the action that is rendering the view. If it is actionCreate, then I know it is a new record. if(Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'create')